# A loose user creation for temporary game room (no account, no password)

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to create a simple game where rooms are generated for game sessions and destroyed after the game ends. I would like to have users join this room to play the game by just entering a nickname.

Would I need to use the meteor user accounts or is there a simpler way to do this as I won't need any authentication or password of sorts.

I am thinking of creating just a player collection and inserting the nickname when they click to join the room, but I don't know how I can keep track of who 'I am' or keep them tracked if they loose connection and have to rejoin.

But if I were to use user accounts, I'm not sure how to customise it so that a casual/loose user can be easily created and probably destroyed after game sessions without any password or email, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to keep the session if users refresh the page?

Comment: @Khang Yes I would need to as I found that sometimes due to connection issues, etc, users might have to refresh the page.

Comment: I do not think user account is necessary. I would have a `Players` collection,  create a new player document for every newly connected browser, and store `_id` of that player in browser by `localStorage`

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a collection, but as you say, you would still need to track the user's id, so that would take some effort.

Personally, I would use the Meteor accounts system, using the accounts-token package:

https://atmospherejs.com/andrei/accounts-token

You can generate a token on the server, and then log the user in. They don't need to know that they are logged in.

Using Meteor's accounts system has many advantages in tracking the user, and if at a later stage you do want people to login using accounts-password, accounts-facebook etc you won't need to restructure your app.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to user Meteor's account system.

Just create a `Rooms` collection and each document inside that collection will be each "game room," or however you want to call it. Then inside, add a "players" key and store all the players or whatever you need (`$pull` player who leaves the game, `$push` player who joins). When the game ends, you can completely remove that MongoDB document via its _id field.

Something like:

```
    db.rooms = {
    _id: xzu90udfmd,
    players: [
    {
    tempUsername: "username1",
    tempWhatever: "whatever",
    token: 3zz97hrnw
    }, {
    tempUsername: "username2",
    tempWhatever: "whatever",
    token: 3zz97hrnw
    }, {
    tempUsername: "username3",
    tempWhatever: "whatever",
    token: 3zz97hrnw
    }
    ]
    };
```

Then, you can add all the customization in either the individual user objects, or outside that could apply to the entire game room. Something like this would be super easy with React.

Comment: But how do I keep track of player if he looses connection, etc? Is it as @khang suggested to keep their _id or token inside localStorage?

Comment: If the person loses connection, do you still want him to be able to connect back to the same room?

Comment: Yeah, you can keep their token in a local storage, load it before the template renders and cross reference it with the `players` array in the DB. If the player tokens match (localstorage/cookie token matches the user's token in the DB) && the game room status is not deleted/finished, render the game room. If not, render a "game over" template or w/e you want.